# FlipClock JS custom increment?

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I am trying to write a custom increment function for FlipClock JS. So that every 5-20 seconds the counter is incremented by 1. I tried surrounding the clock.increment code with a settimeout function, I could not get it to work as I do not know where it is actually looping. I then looked at the flipclock.js file itself I managed to make it go up in 0.5, 0.25 and I can also make it delay start, but I cannot figure out how to make it increment every so often. I thought I could just add something like delay(500) before the clock.increment but I don't think that's where the loop is.

If you need any more info, ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a CDN that hosted flipclock so here is the code.

The counter increments +1 every 5 to 20 seconds.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../compiled/flipclock.css">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="../compiled/flipclock.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;
        var nextDoubleJump;
        var internalCounter;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            internalCounter = 0;
            nextDoubleJump = getRandomIntInclusive(5, 20);
            console.log('Next jump value: ' + nextDoubleJump);

            clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                clockFace: 'Counter',
                autoStart: false,
            });

            setInterval(function(){
                internalCounter += 1;

                console.log(internalCounter);

                if(internalCounter == nextDoubleJump) {
                    clock.increment();
                    nextDoubleJump = getRandomIntInclusive(5, 20) + internalCounter;
                    console.log('Next jump value: ' + nextDoubleJump);
                }

            }, 1000);
        });

        function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```